# Eregi_replace to preg_replace conversion needed

Tags: php, preg-replace, eregi

i need to convert this in order to use preg_replace because eregi_replace is deprecated

```
$n=eregi_replace(")+.+","",$value);
$id=eregi_replace(".+)","<a hсref='http://www.company.com/product.php?id=".$n."'>",$value);
$newstr.="".$id."</a><br>";
//..... must be converted
```

its very unclear to me how that would look in preg_replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$gexpieces = explode(")", $value);
$n=$gexpieces[0];//n is product id
unset($gexpieces[0]);
$prodname = implode($gexpieces);
$newstr.="<a href='http://www.company.com/product.php?id=".$n."'>".$prodname."</a><br/><br/>";
```

nevermind, done it myself.